# How to return array of IDs with Mongoose find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an object model. Is there an alternative to `Mongoose find` that returns an `array of the Ids`?

I want a result like this:

```
["id1", "id2", "id3"]
```

If i used a select on the result of `find()`, I would get an array of objects like this:

```
[{"id": "id1"}, {"id": "id2"}, {"id": "id3"}]
```

But I want an `array of strings`.

Comment: You can apply a `map` function on the Array returned by mongo and make it in the desired format.

Comment: @Cristy  that does it. Thanks